# How do I add a slash at the end of my URLs?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I would like to know how I can add a slash at the end of all my URLs? I already use a .htaccess to remove the .php extension using this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

and I'd like a slash at the end of all my URLs, now. Here is my index.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "index") !== false) { ?>
        <title>Test - Forums</title>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "members") !== false) { ?>
        <title>Test - Members</title>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "sign_up") !== false) { ?>
        <title>Test - Sign Up</title>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "sign_in") !== false) { ?>
        <title>Test - Sign In</title>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "change_theme") !== false) { ?>
        <title>Test - Change Theme</title>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "contact_us") !== false) { ?>
        <title>Test - Contact Us</title>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "help") !== false) { ?>
        <title>Test - Help</title>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "rules") !== false) { ?>
        <title>Test - Rules</title>
        <?php } ?>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include("top_bar.php");?>
        <?php include("header.php");?>
        <?php include("container.php");?>
        <?php include("footer.php");?>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my top_bar.php:

```
<!-- TOP BAR -->
<div id="top_bar">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="top_bar_links">
            <ul>
            <?php
            $full_name = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
            $name_array = explode("/",$full_name);
            $count = count($name_array);
            $page_name = $name_array[$count-1];
            ?>
            <li>
                <a id="home" href="../">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a id="forums" class="<?php echo ($page_name=="index.php")?"active":"";?>" href=".">Forums</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a id="members" class="<?php echo ($page_name=="members.php")?"active":"";?>" href="members">Members</a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

All my files en placed in a folder called "community": http://prntscr.com/487rhj

How can I do, please?

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't post duplicates

Comment: Sorry. My problem is not fixed, yet.

Answer (score -1):

```
href="<?php echo $page_name. "/"; ?>"
```

OR

```
href="<?php echo "{$page_name}/"; ?>"
```

if i understood your question, then any of these should work fine

Comment: Hi, where I place this?